# svcutil not generating class for <element type="..."

Tags: c#, wcf, xsd, svcutil.exe

I have a schema I am trying to compile into data contracts. I have found if an element is defined as `<xs:element name="DogRequest" type="Dog"></xs:element>` no class is generated for DogRequest. I would like to use svcutil as I have multiple namespaces to generate, and xsd.exe only allows one. Plus I have a few elements using the same type, and xsd.exe only generates one of them. Does anyone know if there is a way to generate classes for this schema?

I'm using a generic web service that takes an XML payload. I am hoping use WCF to still build the message.

**Schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="XMLSchema1"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:complexType name="Dog">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="DogRequest" type="Dog"></xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Compiled with `svcutil  /dconly  XMLSchema1.xsd`

This will generate 1 class for Dog, but nothing for DogRequest.

xsd.exe will generate 1 class for Dog with DogRequest

**svcutil output**

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="Dog", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd")]
public partial class Dog : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
{

    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    private string NameField;

    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.extensionDataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.NameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.NameField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**XSD Output**

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("DogRequest", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class Dog {

    private string nameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of the WSDL is incorrect. `DogRequest` is not a type, which is why no class is created. A schema `<element>` defines an xml element that can be used in other parts of the XSD/WSDL to reference the `Dog` complex type.

For example your WSDL probably has a section that says something like:

```
<message name="DogMessage">
    <part name="parameter" element="tns:DogRequest"/>
</message>
```

where `tns` is your target namespace. See the Types section of [Understanding WSDL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996486(d=printer).aspx) for more details.

When the XSD tool adds the `XmlRootAttribute("DogRequest")` to the Dog class, it is defining that the `<DogRequest>` element may be the document root of the xml message and should be serialized/deserialized to/from the `Dog` class.

From [XmlRootAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The XmlRootAttribute allows you to control how the XmlSerializer
>   generates the root element by setting certain properties. For example,
>   specify the name of the generated XML element by setting the
>   ElementName property.

Comment: I'm not using a WSDL, as the web service I'm hitting using a generic method to take an XML payload. I've found if I replace type="..." with <complexContent><extension base="..."> it does generate a class. Does that make sense?

Comment: `<extension base=>` defines an inheritance relationship. Does it make sense that it generates a class? Yes. Question for you: Does it make sense that the `Dog` class inherits from `DogRequest`? Also be warned: Only XmlSerializer will support class inheritance (Data Contract Serializer does not).

Comment: Why do you say Data Contract Serializer does not support inheritance? I have used it for that purpose before and I had no issues. The pattern being used is each request has a complex type like `DogRequestType`, and a `DogRequest` element to make it a root. Thanks for the answer that it is not possible, that has been helpful.